# Query mostrar imagem

Tags: php, imagem

Gostaria de saber se consigo mostrar uma imagem dependendo do nome.

```
 $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
 echo'<div id="tabs-1">
       <p>Nome: '.$exibe["Nome"].'</p>
       <p>Morada:   '.$exibe["Morada"].'</p>
       <p>Distrito: '.$exibe["Distrito"].'</p>
       <p>Concelho: '.$exibe["Concelho"].'</p>
```

Por exemplo:
Mostra-me o nome de uma equipa(Real madrid) e consigo com que ele me mostre o simbolo do mesmo sem mexer na base de dados.

Consigo fazer isso?

Comment: a imagem também está guardada na base de dados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por exemplo, vamos supor que esteja guardado em `Nome` a equipa/time:

```
echo'<img src="/imagens/'.$exibe["Nome"].'.jpg">
```

Aí você salva a imagem como `/imagens/Real Madrid.jpg`.

> A grafia tem que ser idêntica ao que está no DB, inclusive as maiúsculas e minúsculas.
>   Num caso real de uso, o ideal é normalizar os nomes e tirar os espaços e acentos pelo PHP.